# How to insert multiple cursor result set into one table

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

1 table having table structure-

```
 create table tab_abc
 ( id        varchar2(10),
   inv_bfr   varchar2(20),
   desc      varchar2(10),
   inv_afr   varchar2(10)  );
```

I defined 2 cursor here as `C1` & `C2` ->

```
 cursor C1 is select id, count(inv) AS "inv_bfr", desc from tab_a group by id, desc;

 cursor C2 is select count(inv) AS "inv_afr" from tab_a;
```

Result set of both cursor `C1` & `C2` will insert into table `tab_abc`. Cursor `C1` will open before one DML operation perform & cursor `C2` will open after DML operation perform. Could you please help me can i use `OPEN CURSOR THEN FETCH` process would be good or `FOR CURSOR LOOP INSERT INTO TABLE` process.

Comment: Why use a cursor at all? A single `insert ... select ...`  will be much more efficient. And the result of c2 is a single row and a single column. How do you intend to populate the other columns so that you can insert that into the target table

Comment: You want to count `inv` before some DML (what is that doing?), and count `doc_no` afterwards, and be able to see both counts at the same time? You might be looking for a collection rather than a cursor, but it isn't really clear. Your table and column naming is a bit confusing; a more concrete example would help, with consistent sample data and desired results.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Actually select statement in cursor `C1` & `C2` are complicated that's why I am using `cursor` here.

Comment: It would still be helpful to see the data in `tab_a` before and after the DML (and what that is!) and the final result you expect to see.

Comment: "Actually select statement in cursor C1 & C2 are complicated" that is even more reason to NOT use a cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use cursors (or collections, more realistically), or even any PL/SQL here. You can insert data into the table before your 'DML operaton perform' step, and then update if afterwards, e.g. with a merge:

```
-- initial population
insert into tab_abc (id, inv_bfr, descr, inv_afr)
select id, count(*) as inv_bfr, descr, 0 as inv_after
from tab_a
group by id, descr;

-- intermediate DML operation

-- post-DML update
merge into tab_abc t
using (
  select id, 0 as inv_bfr, descr, count(*) as inv_afr
  from tab_a
  group by id, descr
) afr
on (afr.id = t.id and afr.descr = t.descr)
when matched then
  update set inv_afr = afr.inv_afr
when not matched then
  insert (id, inv_bfr, descr, inv_afr)
  values (afr.id, afr.inv_bfr, afr.descr, afr.inv_afr);
```

You can wrap all of that in a PL/SQL block if you need to for other reasons, of course.

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6cb290e599f9c4ea20f1496c33640806) with a few made-up rows.

Comment: But when i use `insert` then after run `merge` statement in shell script then sometimes able to get the proper result but sometimes get `inv_bfr` values as `0`.

Comment: @MdWasi - that implies your DML is creating new IDs, or your real query has filters and your DML is changing data such that IDs that were excluded are now being included.